# getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi in the below code getting an issues Bad Authentication. trying to configuring device but not getting any response.and loader also just dismiss.

Am try to configuring a device using Bluetooth but save data into locally not getting any response .

```
08-23 11:58:33.185 2112-2459/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:743227095>, App: com.android.vending, Service: androidmarket
    gai: Long live credential not available.
        at gaj.b(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):20)
        at gaj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):50)
        at fyt.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):38)
        at hpk.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):8)
        at hpk.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):189)
        at hok.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):2)
        at hoh.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):17)
        at hoh.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):6)
        at cyz.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):25)
        at cyz.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):82)
        at fvp.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):6)
        at fvo.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):2)
        at fvo.e(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):6)
        at fvn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):1)
        at fxk.getAuthToken(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):7)
        at android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator$Transport.getAuthToken(AbstractAccountAuthenticator.java:196)
        at android.accounts.IAccountAuthenticator$Stub.onTransact(IAccountAuthenticator.java:113)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
        at dbf.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):3)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

can any one please help me

```
  @OnClick(R.id.saveConfig)
        public void onClick() {
            sendCommandToBleService();
        }

        private void sendCommandToBleService() {
            String pollNumber = mPollNumber.getText().toString();
            String geoLocation = mGeoLocation.getText().toString();
            String luminairePower = mLuminourPower.getText().toString();
            String projectName = mProjectName.getText().toString();
            String battAh = mBatteryAh.getText().toString();
            String pannelWatt = mPannelWatt.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pollNumber)) {
                Toast.makeText(LightConfigurationActivity.this, R.string.poll_number_blank, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(geoLocation) || geoLocation.equalsIgnoreCase("SET")) {
                Toast.makeText(LightConfigurationActivity.this, R.string.geoLocation_blank, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(luminairePower) || luminairePower.equalsIgnoreCase("SET")) {
                Toast.makeText(LightConfigurationActivity.this, R.string.luminour_power_empty, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(projectName)) {
                Toast.makeText(LightConfigurationActivity.this, R.string.project_name_blank, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(battAh)) {
                Toast.makeText(LightConfigurationActivity.this, R.string.battery_ah_blank, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pannelWatt)) {
                Toast.makeText(LightConfigurationActivity.this, R.string.pannel_watt_blank, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            makeDefaultValues(pollNumber, geoLocation, luminairePower, projectName, battAh, pannelWatt);
            if (battAh.length() == 1) {
                battAh = "00" + battAh;
            } else if (battAh.length() == 2) {
                battAh = "0" + battAh;
            }
            if (pannelWatt.length() == 1) {
                pannelWatt = "00" + pannelWatt;
            } else if (pannelWatt.length() == 2) {
                pannelWatt = "0" + pannelWatt;
            }
            sendCommandsToBleService(battAh, pannelWatt);
        }

        private void resendconfig() {
            sendCommandToBleService();
        }

        private void sendCommandsToBleService(String batAhValue, String pannellwattValue) {
           showProgressDialog();
            String command = mSolarController.generatePacket("pol " + mPollNumber.getText().toString(), "00");
            String longCmd = mPref.getString(Constants.LAT_COMMAND, "");
            String latCmd = mPref.getString(Constants.LONG_COMMAND, "");
            String firstTimerCmd = mPref.getString(Constants.TIMER_ONE_CMD, "");
            String secondTimerCmd = mPref.getString(Constants.TIMER_TWO_CMD, "");
            String projectCmd = mSolarController.generatePacket("pro " + mProjectName.getText().toString(), "00");
            String batAh = mSolarController.generatePacket("battah " + batAhValue, "00");
            String pannelWatt = mSolarController.generatePacket("panelw " + pannellwattValue, "00");
            String wattCommand = mPref.getString(Constants.BRIGHTNESS_CMD, "");
            String luminaryWatt = mPref.getString(Constants.LUMINOURE_WATT_COMMAND, "");
            mBleService.addCommandToQue(command);
            mBleService.addCommandToQue(longCmd);
            mBleService.addCommandToQue(latCmd);
            mBleService.addCommandToQue(firstTimerCmd);
            mBleService.addCommandToQue(secondTimerCmd);
            mBleService.addCommandToQue(projectCmd);
            mBleService.addCommandToQue(batAh);
            mBleService.addCommandToQue(pannelWatt);
            mBleService.addCommandToQue(wattCommand);
            mBleService.addCommandToQue(luminaryWatt);
            mBleService.sendCommandToBle();


}
```